# Finding $a$ such that the complex solutions of $z^4 - 6z^3 + 11az^2 - 3(2a^2 + 3a - 3) z + 1 = 0$ form a parallelogram in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all values of the real number $a$ so that the four complex roots of
$$z^4 - 6z^3 + 11az^2 - 3(2a^2 + 3a - 3) z + 1 = 0$$ form the vertices of a parallelogram in the complex plane.

---

I set $z = x + yi$ due to the given knowledge that $z$ is complex. I then substituted it in, which gave me $$(x+yi)^4 - 6(x+yi)^3 + 11a(x+yi)^2 - 3(2a^2 + 3a - 3)(x+yi) + 1 = 0.$$ However, I'm afraid it's a bit too bashy for it to be viable, so are there any other ways I can get started on this question?

Comment: Hint: $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_2+z_3-z_1$ always form a parallelogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the parallelogram center. Then the roots are $x+y,\,x-y,\,x+z,\,x-z$ for some $y,z$. Then, by Vieta's formulas:
$$\begin{cases}
6=4x\\
6x^2-y^2-z^2=11a\\
4 x^3 - 2 x y^2 - 2 x z^2 = 3(2a^2+3a−3)\\
(x^2-y^2)(x^2-z^2)=1
\end{cases}$$
Although it is doable by hand, too lazy to perform it here, feed it to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%3D4*x%2C+6*x%5E2-y%5E2-z%5E2%3D11*a%2C+4*x%5E3+-+2*x*y%5E2+-+2*x*z%5E2+%3D+3*%282*a%5E2%2B3*a%E2%88%923%29%2C+%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29*%28x%5E2-z%5E2%29%3D1) to get
$$a=1,\quad a=3.$$

Comment: I don't think this is right.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @AlexeyBurdin's answer (in case anyone wants to see *how* to do it by hand), since $x=3/2$ we have $y^2+z^2=27/2-11a$ and$$6a^2+9a-9=27/2-3(y^2+z^2)=33a-27\implies a\in\{1,\,3\}.$$Each such $a$ works viz.$$1=x^4-(y^2+z^2)x^2+y^2z^2=81/16-(27/2-11a)9/4+y^2z^2,$$which we can simplify to obtain $y^2z^2$. We then have the sum and product of $y^2,\,z^2$, and solutions in $\Bbb C$ exist.